# Postgresql batch insert for csv file/dataframe (on GCP)

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, batch-processing

I have a csv file with two columns, `[key, chunk]`, which I need to insert to into a SQL db table. (Amplifying info- Postgresql db hosted on GCP, I'm able to select and perform other db operations fine.)

My csv file has over 10 million rows. And so, I'm curious what's the best batch insert option available to me, specific to Postgresql syntax? Would opening the csv file as a pandas dataframe help at all? Because of the size of the file, I'd like to avoid iterative row insertions.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream large csv files into PostgreSQL with `psql`'s \copy or with `psycog2`'s copy_expert.

Loading it into a panda dataframe first would generally be counterproductive, as it will want to parse it all into memory at once, rather than stream it.

Comment: I see `COPY country TO STDOUT (DELIMITER '|');` listed towards the middle/bottom of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html. Is this it? Looks like I don't need to specify column names or anything as that's detailed in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [import function in Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#gcloud) to load a CSV file in the database. Then, run a query to select the value that you want and to merge them in the target table.

*When you can, prefer the built-in/native feature than self-made!*